# floating point - absolute value - inline assembly - edited new code

Tags: c, assembly

I wrote a function named absD that i want to return the absolute value of its argument..
I am using GCC inline assembly with cygwin..

I dont see why its not working. i m loading into memory. then into st(0)
where i am using fabs - absolute value. Do i have to allocate memory?

I am trying to learn assembly with C here so please be nice. Please give me good help.
Thank you

heres the code and then the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PRECISION   3

double absD (double n)
{


asm(
        "fldl %[nIn]\n"
        "fabs\n"
        "fstpl %[nOut]\n"
        : [nOut] "=m" (n)
        : [nIn] "m" (n)
);



return n;


}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
double  n = 0.0;

printf("Absolute value\n");
if (argc > 1)
    n = atof(argv[1]);

printf("abs(%.*f) = %.*f\n", PRECISION, n, PRECISION, absD(n));

return 0;
}
```

here is the output:

```
~ $ gc a3
gcc -Wall -g a3.c -o a3
~ $ ./a3
Absolute value
abs(0.000) = 0.000
~ $
```

Not outputing its absolute value...
Thank you..

Comment: Why not just include `math.h` and use `fabs( )`?  That will typically be at least as fast as what you have here.  If you want to go faster still, use the GCC-specific intrinsic `__builtin_fabs( )`.

Comment: The absolute value of zero is zero.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely working..!! You are just forgetting to put values to argv. You can run the program with something like this:

./a3 -1.3

and it should return 1.3

you were done before posting it here...

Answer (score 2):

`fld (%eax)` means "load a float from the value at address `%eax`".  Obviously, the contents of `%eax` are a double, and not a pointer to a float, which is why you segfault.

Since the input is already on the stack (thus it has an address), there's no need to jump through hoops moving things around.

```
double absD(double input) {
    double output;
    asm(
            "fldl %[input]\n"
            "fabs\n"
            "fstpl %[output]\n"
            : [output] "=m" (output)
            : [input] "m" (input)
    );
    return output;
}
```

Also, your `printf` format is wrong: `%f` means `float`, but you're giving it a `double`; you want to use `%g`.

Comment: You're wrong about `printf` - because it's a varargs function, it's impossible to pass it a `float` (they're always promoted to `double` when part of the variable-argument-list).  `%f` expects a `double`.

Comment: Why use memory operands at all?  `asm("fabs" : "=t"(input) : "t"(output));` should work, and get the compiler to do the load for you (and leave the result in an FP register, where the return value goes, or where it can be used right away when inlined.  This is still less efficient than avoiding inline asm entirely, because it defeats constant propagation and stuff like that.